# Prevent float right sections overlap the wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have every other section floated a different direction but the sections that are floated right overlap the wrapper. How do I get it to not do that?

Also, I tried incorporating the float into the `nth-child` (`odd`/`even`) of the css and I couldn't get it to work right. If someone can help me do that so I can get rid of the float classes I would be grateful.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdoQPQ

```css
body,
html {
  font: 1em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.vertSection {
  width: 75%;
  height: 175px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888, 0px -3px 5px #888;
  display: inline-block;
}

.vertSection:nth-child(even) {
  float: left;
}

.vertSection:nth-child(odd) {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.vertSection p {
  text-align: left;
}

.vertSection img {
  line-height: 75px;
}

.floatL {
  float: left;
}

.floatR {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <p>This is where some information on my services would go.</p>
  </section>

  <section class="vertSection">
    <img src="images/html5css3.png" class="floatL">

    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <p>A bunch of text and description here!</p>
  </section>

  <section class="vertSection">
    <img src="images/responsive.png" class="floatR">
    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <p>A bunch of text and description here!</p>

  </section>

  <section class="vertSection">
    <img src="images/search.jpg" class="floatL">
    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <p>A bunch of text and description here!</p>
  </section>

  <section class="vertSection">
    <img src="images/communicate.png" class="floatR">

    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <p>A bunch of text and description here!.</p>
  </section>

</section class="">
```

Comment: How about to remove `width: 100%;` on `#wrapper`?

Comment: Sigh. . . Sometimes its the simple things. Thanks man I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely related to this part.

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

So `100% + 10px + 10px` causes the overflow, remove `width:100%` it should all good. By the way, it's safer to also set `section {display:block;}` in case some browsers don't render it as block level element.